# Absolute value of a std::chrono::duration object

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Given that `std::chrono::duration` can represent the signed difference between two times, it would seem a very common case to need the absolute value of such a duration.  For example, the following code outputs `diff: -5` as expected:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

auto now = system_clock::now();
auto then = now - seconds(5);
auto diff = then - now;

cout << "diff: " << duration_cast<seconds>(diff).count() << endl;
```

It would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
auto diff = abs(then - now);
```

However, I can't see any specialization of `std::abs` for the `chrono` templates in the standard, nor can I see any appropriate member function in `std::chrono::duration`.

How should I be transforming a `std::chrono::duration` into it's absolute value?

Comment: I'm curious. In what situation would it be useful?

Comment: Not perfect but: `auto diff = then < now ? now - then : then - now;`

Comment: @user2079303 Any situation where you need to know the time elapsed (`duration`) between two points in time (`time_point`) but don't care which came first.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with more than one use for an `abs(duration)` utility, which might be why it's not standard. I think you're going to have to just apply `std::abs` to the duration's count.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by more than one use.  `std::abs` when applied to `int` has only one use... it removes the sign.  It would be the same with `duration`.  Since `duration` provides all the relevant arithmetic operators it doesn't really make sense to leave out `std::abs` when it has such a clear use case.  After all, we have `std::abs` for `std::complex` and `std::valarray`.

Comment: My point was: When would you not know the order of the `time_point`s?

Comment: Any time you didn't hard code them...  You can always _check_ the order using a conditional, but that introduces potential inefficiency.  For example, if the `time_point` was returned by a function `foo()`, you end up either calling `foo()` multiple times or needing an extra local variable to store the result of `foo()` and an `if` statement.  You can no longer use `time_point` effectively in a single expression (and thus in c++11 `constexpr` functions).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
template <class Rep, class Period>
std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>
abs(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> d)
{
    Rep x = d.count(); 
    return std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>(x >= 0 ? x : -x);
}
```

See my list of [`<chrono>` Utilities](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/duration_io/chrono_util.html) for other `<chrono>` utilities I wish were standard.  Please feel free to use them, recommend them to your standards body representatives, or propose them yourself.

**Update**

I was off my game when I wrote the above.  I'm not deleting it, as it serves as a good lesson for both myself and others on how *not* to write `chrono` utilities.

Things I don't like about it:

1. It needlessly drops type safety by directly manipulating the `Rep`.
2. It assumes that the literal 0 is implicitly convertible to, or at least comparable with `Rep`.
3. There is no reason for this not to be `constexpr`.
4. I'm not happy about the behavior for unsigned `Rep`.  If one says:

   auto d = abs(t1 - t0);

and `t1` and `t0` are based on unsigned durations, then this is likely a logic bug in the code.  If `t1 < t0`, then you are likely to get an incorrect, very large duration.  If that is what you really want, then you shouldn't be using `abs`, and instead just code the simpler:

```
   auto d = t1 - t0;
```

To address these concerns I've rewritten `abs` for durations as:

```
template <class Rep, class Period,
          class = typename std::enable_if
          <
              std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>::min() <
              std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>::zero()
          >::type
         >
constexpr
inline
std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>
abs(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> d)
{
    return d >= d.zero() ? d : -d;
}
```

1. `duration` has unary `-`, just use it.
2. `duration` has a customizable `zero` trait just so that one doesn't have to assume an intimate cooperation with `0` from `Rep`.  Just use it.
3. All of the operations used are `constexpr`, marked `abs` with `constexpr`.
4. The static functions `min` and `zero` are `constexpr`.  Using these to determine if `Rep` is signed is more general than using a trait such as `!std::is_unsigned`.  I.e. `Rep` might be a `BigNum`, or a C11 `timespec` (augmented with overloaded arithmetic operators).  So the question "is signed" is answered with `min() < zero()`.  And now this version of `abs` will not accept a `duration<unsigned, milli>` (for example).

Comment: `std::chrono::abs` will be in C++17.

Comment: You're welcome: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0092r1.html ;-)